# Oozie workflow to load data to hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, hue

my task is to create an oozie workflow to Load Data to Hive tables every hour.

i am using Hue 2.3.0

When i run the command: LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/username1/data/data3.txt' INTO TABLE raw_data;
it works perfectly, data gets loaded to the hive table.

****When i run the same command on oozie workflow the job get killed at 66% and the error message is**** Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [10001]

May you please help.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Could you resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Hue demos about how to run Hive queries in a workflow and then with a coordinator:

- [Hive queries in an Oozie workflow](http://gethue.tumblr.com/post/60937985689/hadoop-tutorials-ii-2-execute-hive-queries-and)
- [Schedule repetitive Hive queries](http://gethue.tumblr.com/post/61597968730/hadoop-tutorials-ii-3-schedule-hive-queries-with)

The most important is too configure Hive Metastore as remote and add the hive-site.xml as a file and in the 'Job XML' attribute of the Hive action.

Comment: Hi Romain, Thanks for your response n referral to the Tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide your log, so we can see the actual message that failed the action.

Also, you need to paste your Workflow action, so we can see how you've built it.